# C++ console application outputs nothing and won't quit? Codeblocks MinGW GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, console-application, codeblocks

I have a C++ application which is build statically against libcurl. The application compiles perfectly, however when I execute the application it returns nothing on the console. Neither it shows anything when I redirect the output to e.g. `> output.txt`.

The code is just:

```
int main(void) {
   cout << "Show me" << endl; //Or not... :(
   return 0;
}
```

When executed it just starts the console and keeps black, nothing is happening.

Comment: _"When executed it ..."_ Hcw are you doing so? Is [this](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=20692.0) helpful?

Comment: Doesn't matter, at least it doesn't mind. I execute by clicking the .exe file which popups the console but shows nothing. When I start it by opening the command line and than starting the .exe file it also shows me nothing